# dynamically hide textbox based on radio button checked state

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a set of radio buttons with corresponding textboxes on an aspx page. I want the textboxes to either show or hide depending on their relative radio button checked state.

During page load, I'm pulling all of the controls on the panel, looping through each one and if it's typeof is radiobutton I add the javascript function to the radio button to run onchange. Based on the radio checked state, the function will show or hide the textbox. I wasn't sure how to tell the function which textbox to hide based on the radio button other than to make my own attribute for the radio button and use that in the page_load. This, to me, is the best solution I've come up with short of in-lining the JS function calls.

But even this isn't working.

Regardless of the functionality of my code, this isn't how I want to do it. I want to get a list or array of radio buttons from the panel  (instead of grabbing all of the controls), and add the function to it. And adding an attribute to the radio button just doesn't seem to be the cleanest way nor does in-lining all the calls. Regardless of the solution path chosen, I still need to know the textbox that I'm hiding or showing that goes along with the radio button. So any and all help, ideas, and wisdom will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="divPersonnel" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; width: 95%;
                display: block; vertical-align: middle;">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlPersonnel" runat="server">
                    <div style="width: 300px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
                        <asp:Table runat="server" BorderStyle="None" ID="tblPersonnelQuerySelect">
                            <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbID" runat="server" textbox="txbID"/>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblID" runat="server" Text="ID:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbFN" runat="server" textbox="txbFN"/>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblFname" runat="server" Text="First Name:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbFN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbLN" runat="server" textbox="txbLN"/>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblLName" runat="server" Text="Last Name:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbLN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbPR" runat="server" textbox="txbPR"/>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblRate" runat="server" Text="Pay Rate:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TextBox class="right" ID="txbPR" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbSD" runat="server" textbox="dtpkrSD"/><br />
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbED" runat="server" textbox="dtpkrED"/>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Label class="left" ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date:" Style=""></asp:Label>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell>
                                    <input class="right" id="dtpkrSD" onclick="$(this).datepicker();"/><br />
                                    <input class="right" id="dtpkrED" onclick="$(this).datepicker();"/>
                                </asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                        </asp:Table>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function toggletxb(rdb, txb) {
        if ($(rdb).attr('checked') == true) {
            $(txb).show();
        }
        else { $(txb).hide(); }
    }
```

C# (runs in Page_Load):

```
Control[] ctrsPersonnel = new Control[pnlPersonnel.Controls.Count];
        pnlPersonnel.Controls.CopyTo(ctrsPersonnel, 0);

        foreach (Control _ctr in ctrsPersonnel)
        {
            if (_ctr.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
            {
                ((RadioButton)_ctr).Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleCheckedState($(this));toggletxb($(this), $(#" + ((RadioButton)_ctr).["textbox"] + ");");
                continue;
            }
            else if (_ctr.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                ((TextBox)_ctr).Attributes.Add("onload", "$(this).hide();");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

######   EDIT   ############

I ended up using the element ids in an array and looping through each index to add the attribute 'onclick' and the functions for that attribute.

html remained the same and the c# has been removed.

```
 //checkbox ids
    var checks = ['<%= chbID.ClientID%>', '<%= chbFN.ClientID%>', '<%= chbLN.ClientID%>', '<%= chbPR.ClientID%>', '<%= chbDtPkrSD.ClientID%>', '<%= chbDtPkrED.ClientID%>',
                        '<%= chbUID.ClientID%>', '<%= chbUsername.ClientID%>', '<%= chbActivityID.ClientID%>', '<%= chbIP.ClientID %>', '<%= chbFormAccessed.ClientID %>', '<%= chbDOA.ClientID %>'];

// text box ids
    var texts = ['<%= txbID.ClientID%>', '<%= txbFN.ClientID%>', '<%= txbLN.ClientID%>', '<%= txbPR.ClientID%>', 'txbDtPkrSD', 'txbDtPkrED',
                        '<%= txbUID.ClientID%>', '<%= txbUsername.ClientID%>', '<%= txbActivityID.ClientID%>', '<%= txbIP.ClientID %>', '<%= txbFormAccessed.ClientID %>', 'dtpkrDOA'];


//loop through each id and add the functions
        for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
            $('#' + checks[i]).attr('onclick', 'toggletxb($(this),$("#' + texts[i] + '"))');
            $('#' + texts[i]).hide();
        }
```

######   END EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard,

Since your radio buttons and textboxes are not generated dynamically, in other words they are hard coded in the html, then I would suggest that you use client side code. Try to use input type="radio" instead of asp radio buttons. add the onclick = yourfunction(this); notice there is no $ sign.

Once the onclick event has fired up then you can look for your textbox using the clientId as opposed to the server id.

Example:
var mytextbox = $get("<%=Textbox1.ClientID%>");

I hope this helps

Comment: It does help! but it doesnt completely solve my issue. using straight html would work, but that forces me to add the function to each radio input. that would be ok using jQuery to select all the radio buttons in the given panel and adding the function one by one in a loop (as opposed to inlining). However, generating the buttons and textboxes dynamically may be what I need as I could then set everything I need to set. Basically, I would want to use the database field names for the input names so i could just drop them back into my select sql.  Could you provide some guidance on how to do this?

Comment: Richard, generating your textboxes and radio buttons dynamically from a SQL database table poses a new set of challenges. I have done this before using AJAX. The best way to go about this is to return an array or collection with your table columns names, from an AJAX method. When your AJAX method returns to your client, iterate collection and dynamically create your html controls using JavaScript and add to a div. this will definitely work and will not cause a post back. To save everything back to the database, again use AJAX to allow a web service method to save your data client side.

Comment: from a security standpoint, thats not a good way of dynamically generating inputs based on the database schema. It gives everything to the client. but building the html before its sent to the client prevents that security risk.

All that aside, I'm still having issues making this work. I've changed from radio buttons to check boxes because it makes more sense and I've moved the code that adds the onclick event to the boxes into the page and rewrote in javascript. but I'm getting a jquery error saying: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#chbID'

@fernan, all help is greatly appreciated =)

Comment: I'm choosing this as the answer because it helped; however I worked around the problem and found another working solution. Check edit on question. I used the $get("<%=Textbox1.ClientID%>") in my code